# iFrame page refresh start onload

Tags: javascript

The code below refreshes the iframe only when the drop down is selected. This is great, but it will only start when someone changes the intial value.

I am trying to get it to start up when the parent page loads to a default value of 1 minute unless the value has been changed since.

So if default value is 1 minute on page load, user selects 5 minutes and then refreshes the parent page, 5 minutes is displayed and the timer autoamtically starts from that selection. But if a user loads the parent page for the first time, 1 minute is displayed and starts the timer.

I have tried loading in an onload function but i cant get it to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>refresh</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var interval = 0;
var auto_refresh = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#reload_interval').change(function() {
    var reload = $(this).val();
    interval = reload * 1000;
    if (auto_refresh) {
      clearInterval(auto_refresh);
    }
    if (reload) {
      auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
          // function to run
        document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.location.reload();
          //
      }, interval);
    }

  });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<select id="reload_interval">
  <option></option>
  <option value='10'>10 sec</option>
  <option value='30'>30 sec</option>
  <option value='60'>1 min</option>
  <option value='300'>5 min</option>
  <option value='600'>10 min</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" src="test.html" style="border-style: none; border:0px; background-color:transparent;" frameborder="0" width="743" height="300"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the selected value to persist you'll have to store that value somewhere, so I chose [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).  Take a look at the code below, and it should do everything you are asking w/ some notes to point out where things happen.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>refresh</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

  $(function (){

    // Set interval from localStorage or set it to 1 minute.
    var interval = localStorage.interval ? localStorage.interval : 60000;
    var autoRefresh;

    // Separate function for setting interval to keep things clean.
    var setter = function (val) {
      var currentInterval = setInterval(function () {
        $('iframe').attr('src', 'test.html');
      }, val);
      return currentInterval;
    }

    // Create our handler function for the change event.
    $('#reload_interval').change(function () {
      // Update interval & localStorage.interval values
      interval = $(this).val() * 1000;
      localStorage.interval = interval;

      // Clear our old interval and/or set the new one
      if (autoRefresh) { clearInterval(autoRefresh); }
      autoRefresh = setter(interval);
    });

    // Set the <select> tag value
    $('#reload_interval').val(localStorage.interval / 1000);
    // Fire the change event to set things going.
    $('#reload_interval').trigger('change');
  });


</script>

</head>
<body>

<select id="reload_interval">
  <option></option>
  <option value='10'>10 sec</option>
  <option value='30'>30 sec</option>
  <option value='60'>1 min</option>
  <option value='300'>5 min</option>
  <option value='600'>10 min</option>
</select>

<br><br>

<iframe id="iframe" name="iframe" src="test.html" style="border-style: none; border:0px; background-color:transparent;" frameborder="0" width="743" height="300"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Levi Mootz, many thanks for this and the code points, this has helped greatly and it makes sense. I have noticed two issues which i cant seem to fix.

1. when the page loads, it goes into a loop beacuse the first dropdown value is "0".

2. when the iframe refreshes it sends it back to the test.html document, how do we get this to reload the current page its on? for example this code snipped did that `document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.location.reload();`

Comment: This has fixed my issue, i have added an if statement to stop the page refreshing in a loop

`if (interval > 0) { autoRefresh = setter(interval); }`

and i have added the above code snippet which has allowed the frame to reload on its current page and not reload back to the default test.html page.

Thank you for your help on this